# A burning organization... of guys?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

Steal my prefix and fire shall arise.
Steal my suffix and someone dies.
Steal my infix and differ from guys.
Steal my whole and go reorganize.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> **HANGER**

*Steal my prefix and fire shall arise.*

> Remove ('steal') the prefix '**H**' and **ANGER** *arises* (a feeling associated with the intensity of a raging *fire*).

*Steal my suffix and someone dies.*

> Remove the suffix '**ER**' and someone might **HANG** (i.e die at the end of a rope).

*Steal my infix and differ from guys.*

> Remove the infix '**ANG**' and we have **HER** - a female pronoun (rather than a male one for *guys*).

*Steal my whole and go reorganize.*

> If the **HANGER**s in my wardrobe are stolen, I will need to find a way to *reorganise* my clean clothes!